# Nobody in Big Town

Tags: fallout-3

I've saved Red and Shorty, brought them back to Big Town, healed Timebomb and fixed the Sentry Bot. Then I went exploring further.
After some time, when I traveled back to the city, there was the Sentry Bot and a Protectron, but nobody else. Almost immediately about 5 Super Mutants attacked, so I shot them. But there is noone around aside from the bots. All the buildings are empty and there are no bodies.

I want my Lucky-8-Ball!

Anyone has any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try waiting in Megaton for a week and coming back, they may find their way back, if they are alive.

If you're on PC, you can use

> prid 0002805b
>
> moveto player

in the console to move Timebomb to your position

Answer (score 0):

Big Town is notorious for being the victim of random creature attacks. If the creature killed the people and the robots killed the creature you will not see evidence unless the bpts are missing health (assuming they even got hit). The muties were caused by you fast traveling there and probably were not the cause of their deaths.